# Find all revisons made for a particular entity in Hibernate Envers?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

Is there a functionality within envers to query for all revisions made for a particular entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/envers/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queries.html#revisions-of-entity), it gives you some nice tools for audit queries.

What you are looking for is probably something like [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/envers/query/AuditQueryCreator.html#forRevisionsOfEntity(java.lang.Class,%20boolean,%20boolean))

```
AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(session);
AuditQuery query = reader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(MyEntity.class, false, true);
List result = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: More specifically, Is there a way to get just revisions numbers for a specific entity?

Comment: Yes, even simpler: `reader.getRevisions(MyEntity.class, id)`. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/envers/AuditReader.html#getRevisions(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object)

Comment: Awesome. One more thing. Is there way, I can show what type of revision was made? for example was it an create, update or delete etc.

Comment: The example from my answer will give you back a list of three-element arrays, first being an entity instance and third being the `RevisionType` instance (read the docs from the link I posted). However, I am not aware of a method that will give you back just revision number and revision type, if that is what you need.

Comment: Is there a way I could possibly achieve it?

Comment: Can't test this, but you could try with projections, something like `AuditQuery query = reader.createQuery()
    .forRevisionsOfEntity(MyEntity.class, false, true)
    .addProjection(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().distinct())
    .addProjection(AuditEntity.revisionType()).add(AuditEntity.id().eq(id))`. Expriment with it, I don't expect it to work as it is

Comment: I will thanks. What exactly does .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(id)) mean?

Comment: 'id' parameter should be replaced with id of the entity you want revisions for. But, as I said, can't test this myself so I can't guarantee this'll work

Comment: Can you help with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29371000/unable-to-fetch-object-in-hibernate-envers