# Unable to fetch Object in Hibernate Envers

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I'm trying to display the values in the RefAuthorizationVO Object when I call the DuaVO Object. But, when I debug it, the value is shown as null.

[image: DUA Class]

I'm passing an authorizationCode as "BENE" and wanted the particular column fetch from the RefAuthorization Table.

[image]

But, I all I see is a null. I'm kinda lost here.
[image]

Main Class

```
    public void getDuaObject() {

        // findAuditByRevision("DuaNum", Revision Number);
        DuaVO dua = findAuditByRevisionNum("1", 1026);

}
```

Comment: What if you call `dua.getRefAuthorizationVO()`? It is lazy fetched, so it's possible Eclipse is showing it as null because it uses reflection to display actual field value in the debug window.

Comment: It gave me a null when I did it.

Comment: Well, you have the `@NotAudited` annotation so that field is not audited? :)

Comment: @adamw But, That table already has values and it is not supposed to be audited.

Comment: which table? you marked the refAuthorizationVO field as not audited so you are getting null values when reading their history

Comment: Getting the object now. But, I changed to Eager fetching from Lazy... Im getting RefAuth as a proxy object.